# Picklist error in Flow using dynamic pages/component visibility

Tags: visual-workflow

I've got a flow with screens for different teams that creates a case. On one screen, I've set up component visibility on several fields based on the value set in the first picklist on the page so that users can complete a subset of fields on the same page once they set the value in the first field. The problem is that the flow is not advancing past this screen to create a case, it just reloads the same screen and shows no errors. If I go back a page or change the first value, I see this error on all the picklists where component visibility is set:

> "Whether a choice is selected can only be set to true. Choices that
>   aren't selected shouldn't be included in the request. An administrator
>   needs to resolve this error."

It doesn't matter if the picklist is set with individual choices or with a picklist choice variable. The error only appears on picklist fields and no other fields. The criteria on the component visibility is pretty straightforward:

```
{!Server_ASP_Details_DBA} Equals {!SchemaorTestSchemaSetup}
```

OR

```
{!Server_ASP_Details_DBA} Equals {!RestoreData}
```

The Server ASP Details DBA field is the picklist that drives the component visibility on all the other fields on the page.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?